# Java Looping issues

Tags: java, string, loops, do-while

I have around 15 String variables as follows...

```
String jack = "blue, orange, green, purple";

String blue = "Yellow, red";

String yellow = "sky, wind, earth";

String orange  = "char1, char2 , char3";
```

I am trying to add the String 'Jack' into a arrayList. I am using split function ( to split on the "'')to add them to a arrayList.

All I am trying to do is when i get to the "blue" in the jack String, I will have to add the "Yellow" and "Red" to the arraylist before I add "orange" and so on.

How do I achieve this ? thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a question on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . At a minimum, we need you to show us your code and tell us what specifically is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This act of using the variable's name is called Reflection. This is probably not what you want to be doing.

You can initialize a `HashMap` to (probably) achieve what you want:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
map.put("jack", Array.asList("blue", "orange", "green", "purple"));
map.put("blue", Array.asList("yellow", "red"));
map.put("yellow", Array.asList("sky", "wind", "earth"));
map.put("orange", Array.asList("char1", "char2", "char3"));

List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : map.get("jack")) {
    if (map.get(s) != null) {
        for (String s2 : map.get(s)) { results.add(s2); }
    }    
}
```

You didn't mention if you want to do it recursively (such as whenever you hit a colour, use that colour's list). I didn't implement it as such, but if you need it you should push and pop from a stack (similar to a depth first search).

Comment: an off-topic comment: in situation here, it is better to use `Array.asList("blue", "orange")` instead of the anonymous-class-with-initializer trick (new ArrayList<>(){{ add(...); add(...)}}`) for the sake of readability.

Comment: @AdrianShum Thanks, I'll change it to use that. Much nicer!

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to use the name of a variable as part of the logic in your code is almost certainly reflecting a design problem. The resulting code will be fragile and hard to read. Unless you are forced to use that code without changes then I would suggest refactoring to use a different approach:

```
Map<String, List<String>> colours = new HashMap<>();
colours.put("blue", Arrays.asList("yellow", "red"));
colours.put("yellow", Arrays.asList("sky", "wind", "earth"));
colours.put("orange", Arrays.asList("char1", "char2", "char3"));

String result = Arrays.stream(jack.split(", "))
    .map(str -> colours.getOrDefault(str, str))
    .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
```